# How to clear cache after database updates?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, caching, laravel-artisan

I am trying to clear cache after some table updates.

In controller's store functions i am adding

```
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

But this is not a good way to do that. I made observers to do this. But this is repeating itself too.

For example i have users, categories, posts, visitors table.
If categories and posts tables are updated cache must clear. But i can't made this clearly. Can i write clear code for this? Any idea would be good. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one example of clear code:

Create file in app/Traits/CacheClear.php, and put this code:

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait CacheClear
{

    /**
     * Boot function for Laravel model events.
     * https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        /**
         * After model is created, or whatever action, clear cache.
         */
        static::updated(function () {
            Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        });
    }
```

Now, just in case, run `composer dump-autoload`.

After that go to your model and use the trait,

`use App\Traits\CacheClear;`

`class User extends Model {
   use CacheClear;
}`

Each time you fire `update` event on the User model, command will be called :)

Comment: For some weird reason, code formatting is messed on the Stack, here's how it should look: https://imgur.com/e7sy7hK

Comment: This will work like a charm. Trying as soon as possible. Thanks :)